# GCD and Number Theory

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

I need help with a proof that begins as follows:

"We are given that $(a-c)(a+c)=(d-b)(d+b)$. If $\gcd(a-c, d-b)=k$ and $\gcd(a+c, d+b)=k$, prove that $h$ and $k$ are relatively prime."

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Let $$\dfrac{a+c}p=\dfrac{d+b}q=k\implies(p,q)=1$$

Comment: It seems that you haven't finished your answer as this does not shed any more light on the problem that I am having with this proof. Can you elaborate please.